# Eclipse start up menu

Tags: java, eclipse

What is the window which is displayed when you first install Eclipse called, and how can I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Help -> Welcome

That thing?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the splash screen?

You can change it if you need (for example, your own RCP or a version of Eclipse like IBM's WSAD). Read about branding your application

(eg.,http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Branding/branding-your-application.html)